# Finding the volume by triple integration

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume of the solid bounded by the planes $x = 0, y = 0, z = x, z = 2,$ and $y = 4– x^2$ in first quadrant?

what's the right triple integration set up for finding the volume of this?
only cartesian

Comment: Welcome to the website. Good job with the Mathjax! What have you tried? Are you able to draw a figure?

Comment: Thanks very much 
$\int_0^2\int_x^2\int_0^{4-x^2}dydzdx$
 This is what I've tried but I don't know if it's true or wrong

Comment: Yes, the integral is correct.